# Storing Facebook photos on my system

Tags: performance, facebook, photo

My application is joined at the hip with the facebook application. I show the user's photo and their friends from facebook. I am debating between storing the user (and their friends) photo on my system. What is better for the system performance? Is it better to store the photos in my system or retrieve them facebook at run-time?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your system has some inherent advantages (like local storage), Facebook's server setup is likely to be more optimized than your own. For example:

1. They use CDN's, so unless you also do their requests will take fewer network hops.
2. They likely have servers in more geographic locations than you likely do so on average a user will reach one of their servers in fewer hops than yours.

The best way to find out though is to test.